# Крестики нолики 10 х 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

Никак не получается реализовать функцию, которая считает крестики и нолики по диагонали, вертикали и горизонтали, вычисляя победителя.

Побеждает линия из ***пяти*** символов.

Функцию, которую пишу сейчас, но она не работает:

```
def who_win(self):
    for y in range(10):
        for x in range(10):
            ch = self.board[y][x]
            win = True
            for i in range(1, 11):
                if self.board[y + i][x + i] != ch:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                if ch == 'X':
                    self.winner = 'X'
                elif ch == 'O':
                    self.winner = 'O'
    for y in range(4, 10):
        for x in range(6):
            ch = self.board[y][x]
            win = True
            for i in range(1, 10):
                if self.board[y - i][x + i] != ch:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                if ch == 'X':
                    self.winner = 'X'
                elif ch == 'O':
                    self.winner = 'O'
    return self.winner
```

Comment: @S. Nick, по поводу меток: тут нигде в вопросе нет ничего про gui, не нужно добавлять эту метку. Вопрос про реализацию проверки, а не про реализацию в графическом интерфейсе. Вы фактически пытаетесь подогнать метки вопроса к своему ответу.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде не обрабатываются горизонтальные и вертикальные комбинации. Ещё смешана обработка крестиков и ноликов.

`check_winner_1` проверяет конкретный символ и конкретное направление выигрышной комбинации. `check_winner` проверяет четыре направления для одного символа. `who_win` проверяет оба символа.

```
def who_win(self):

    def check_winner_1(c, dx, dy, xr, yr):
        for x in xr:
            for y in yr:
                if all(
                    self.board[y + dy * i][x + dx * i] == c
                    for i in range(5)
                ):
                    return True
        return False

    def check_winner(c):
        return \
            check_winner_1(c, 1,  0, range( 6), range(   10)) or \
            check_winner_1(c, 0,  1, range(10), range(    6)) or \
            check_winner_1(c, 1,  1, range( 6), range(    6)) or \
            check_winner_1(c, 1, -1, range( 6), range(4, 10))

    self.winner = None
    for c in ('X', 'O'):
        if check_winner(c):
            self.winner = c
            break
    return self.winner
```

Немного другой дизайн. `get_range` вычисляет промежуток для возможных значений координаты, `wins` перебирает все возможные положения полоски из пяти выигрышных знаков:

```
def who_win(self):

    def get_range(d):
        return range(max(0, -5 * d - 1), min(10, 10 - 5 * d + 1))

    def wins(c):
        for dx, dy in ((1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1)):
            for x in get_range(dx):
                for y in get_range(dy):
                    yield all(
                        self.board[y + dy * i][x + dx * i] == c
                        for i in range(5)
                    )

    self.winner = None
    for c in ('X', 'O'):
       if any(wins(c)):
            self.winner = c
            break
    return self.winner
```

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовал реализовать вашу задумку
с использованием библиотеки **`numpy`**,
а заодно и визуализировать с использованием **`PyQt5`**.

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили *PyQt5*

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

*PyQt* — реализация фреймворка *Qt* для языка *Python*.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import numpy as np                                # pip install numpy
from numpy.lib.twodim_base import fliplr


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(50, 50)        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: green;")        
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        many_buttons = 100                       # хотим создать 100 кнопок
        column = 10                              # 10 столбцов
        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.buttons = []
        
        for step in range(many_buttons):
            btn = PushButton()   
            row = step // column
            col = step % column
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, b=btn, r=row, c=col: 
                self.onClicked(b, [r, c]))        
            layout.addWidget(btn, row, col)  
            self.buttons.append(btn)

        self.label_win = QLabel()
        self.label_win.setStyleSheet("color: #AF460F; font-size: 26px;")
        layout.addWidget(self.label_win, 12, 1, 1, 3) 
        
        self.button_clean_up = QPushButton('Restart')
        self.button_clean_up.clicked.connect(self.clean_up)
        self.button_clean_up.setStyleSheet("color: #AF460F; font-size: 26px;")
        layout.addWidget(self.button_clean_up, 12, 6, 1, 3) 

        self.board = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=int)
        self.marca = "X"

    def onClicked(self, btn, cord):
        if self.marca == "X":
            btn.setStyleSheet("color: green")
            btn.setText("X")
            self.board[cord[0], cord[1]] = 1
        else:
            btn.setStyleSheet("color: red")
            btn.setText("O")
            self.board[cord[0], cord[1]] = -1

        if self.check():
            self.label_win.setText(f"Выиграл: `{self.marca}`")
            for b in self.buttons:
                b.setDisabled(True)        
        self.marca = "O" if self.marca == "X" else  "X"      
        btn.setDisabled(True)
        
    def check(self): 
        z1 = np.zeros((11, 10), dtype=int)
        r = 0
        for ki in range(-5, 6):                
            d = np.diag(self.board, k=ki)
            for c, v in enumerate(d):
                z1[r, c] = v
            r += 1

        z2 = np.zeros((11, 10), dtype=int)
        r = 0
        for ki in range(-5, 6):                
            d = np.diag(np.fliplr(self.board), k=ki)
            for c, v in enumerate(d):
                z2[r, c] = v
            r += 1

        for i in range(6):
            if  abs(np.sum(self.board[0, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[1, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[2, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[3, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[4, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[5, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[6, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[7, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[8, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[9, i:i+5])) == 5 :
                return True
            if  abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 0])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 1])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 2])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 3])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 4])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 6])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 7])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 8])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(self.board[i:i+5, 9])) == 5 :
                return True

            if  abs(np.sum(z1[0, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[1, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[2, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[3, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[4, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[5, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[6, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[7, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[8, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[9, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z1[10, i:i+5])) == 5 :
                return True
            if  abs(np.sum(z2[0, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[1, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[2, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[3, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[4, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[5, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[6, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[7, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[8, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[9, i:i+5])) == 5 or \
                abs(np.sum(z2[10, i:i+5])) == 5 :
                return True
        return False

    def clean_up(self):
        self.marca = "X"
        self.board = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=int)
        self.label_win.clear()
        for b in self.buttons:
            b.setText("")
            b.setDisabled(False)
            b.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: green;")
         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setFixedSize(575, 620)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]